# lingo/lindo math statistics homework help

Tags: statistics, linear-programming

Can anyone provide guidance on answering these questions? I have no idea how to use lingo/lindo software but did generate excel answers. But the required format is Lingo.

Link to pdf attached

http://docdro.id/zN2mj1O

Comment: This stack exchange is about mathematics, not about specific software uses. So I belive this question is off-topic.

Comment: @Eff we have a `matlab` tag and people post Mathematica questions here regularly. I am sure there will be a couple Lingo users happy to help the OP

Comment: @gt6989b The `matlab` tag is about *mathematical* questions about matlab. Within the tag it specifically says that syntax is off-topic. Of course, some questions about matlab syntax are still answered, but whatever.

Comment: @Eff i agree, but most of the questions are `how do you do this in Matlab`, quite similar to what I understand the OP is asking here...

Comment: @gt6989b: this is plain-vanilla homework on using Lingo. I side with Eff.

Comment: @mlc why don't you or Eff raise the flag for the admin review then...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to solve these problems for you , but I will give you some general guidance. Lindo takes a fairly simple text-based format of an LP and solves it for you.

Suppose you had this LP to solve:

First line must be the objective function. Something like:

```
  max 3x + 2y
```

Next line must be

```
  st
```

This stands for "such that."

Next come the constraints, eg:

```
  x+2y<12
  2x<6
```

These must have all the variables and their coefficients on the $LHS$ and the constant term on the $RHS$.

You don't need to specify that the variables are positive: Lindo will assume this unless told otherwise.

Finally you may need to declare the types of variables:

```
  int x
```

if you want $x$ to be an "indicator variable" (restricted to 0 or 1).

```
  gin y
```

if you want $y$ to be an "general integer" (integer).

```
  free z
```

if you want $z$ to be negative as well as positive.

Finally finish with the statement:

```
  end
```

Lindo doesn't distinguish between upper and lower case. Variable names can include numbers as well as letters but must not start with a letter.

---

I've now started solving those problems - how are you getting on?

---

Question I

Let $x$ be the number of ounces of Dried Fruit used in your blend.

Let $y$ be the number of ounces of Nut Mix used in your blend.

Let $z$ be the number of ounces of Cereal Mix used in your blend.

Let $c$ be the total cost. $c=0.35x+0.50y+0.20z$

Although some software will allow variables on both sides of the LP formulation, Lindo will not be happy with this.

Simple rearrangement gives us $c-0.35x-0.50y-0.20z=0$

Calorie constraint: $150x+400y+50z<1000$

Note that in Lindo there is no distinction between $<$ and $\le$.

Fat constraint : $10y+z<25$ (as a British mathematician / scientist I find the casual mixing of ounces, cups and grams so very American)

Although not strictly necessary I find it helpful to create a new variable $v$ that represents the total volume: $v=0.25x+0.375y+z$

Of course this needs to be written as $v-0.25x-0.375y-z=0$ for the benefit of Lindo.

The volume of dried fruit needs to be at least 20% of the total volume.

$0.25x \ge 0.2v$ will be written as $0.25x-0.2v >0$

We could substitute $v=0.25x+0.375y+z$ into this to get $0.25x-0.2(0.25x+0.375y+z) >0$.

This becomes $0.25x-0.05x - 0.075y-0.2z >0 \Rightarrow 0.2x - 0.075y-0.2z >0$

I don’t see any benefit to this – it is quite useful having $v$ as a separate variable as you will see.

The volume of nuts needs to be at most 15% of the total volume.

$0.375y \le 0.15v$ will be written as $0.375y-0.15v <0$

The total volume must be between $3$ and $4$ cups. Mathematically we would write this as $3 \le 0.25x + 0.375y + z \le 4$ but Lindo will require this as two separate inequalities and we already have our variable $v$ in use.

$v < 4$

$v > 3$

Combining all of these into a single file for Lindo:

```
min c
st
c-0.35x-0.50y-0.20z=0
150x+400y+50z<1000
10y+z<25$
v-0.25x-0.375y-z=0
0.25x-0.2v >0
0.375y-0.15v <0
v<4
v>3
end
```

---

Question II

This is a pretty standard transportation problem, although the shipping costs are a bit ambiguous. I will assume that those are the costs per unit being shipped.

Let $AX$ be the the number of units being shipped from A to X etc.

You want to minimise the total cost $COST$ which is given by:

$COST = 3AX+2AY+5AZ+ ...$

Lindo will want that as $COST - 3AX-2AY-5AZ ... =0$

The total shipped from A must be less than the supply at A:

$AX+AY+AZ<200$

Do similarly for B and C. Remember you can't ship from B to Z.

The total shipped to X must be equal to the demand:

$AX+BX+CX=50$

Do similarly for Y and Z. Remember you can't ship from B to Z.

```
min COST
st
COST - 3AX-2AY-5AZ - ... =0
AX+AY+AZ<200
BX+ ...
CX+ ...
AX+BX+CX=50
AY+ ...
AZ+ ...
end
```

---

Question III

There is a fairly standard implementation for the shortest route problem. This time your variables are 'indicator variables' - sometimes called 'binary variables'. Basically they are 'on' or 'off': '0' or '1'.

Let $x_{12}$ be an indicator variable telling whether the route from node 1 to node 2 is used (takes value 1) or not used (takes value 0).

The distance travelled $d$ is given by adding up the distance along each arc multiplied by the indicator variable for that arc.

Mathematically that is $d=\Sigma_{i,j} d_{ij}x_{ij}$

For Lindo we will write:

```
d-10x12-12x13-4x24-8x25-7x35 ... =0
```

The start node must have exactly one route leaving it:

```
x12+x13=1
```

The destination node must have exactly one route entering it:

```
x47+x57+x67=1
```

All other nodes have no more than one leaving and no more than one entering:

```
x25+x35+x45<1
x57<1
```

All these nodes must also be left if they are entered:

```
x25+x35+x45-x57=0
```

---

Question IV

Badly written question. The first line says the variables are $x$ and $y$ but later they use $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Let $x_1$ be the number of tables and let $x_2$ be the number of chairs.

Maximise your profit $p$, where $p=3x_1+2x_2$. Lindo will want that expression rearranged.

Wood constraint: $3x_1+2x_2 \le 9$

Electricity constraint $x_1+3x_2 \le 7$

Technical constraint: $-x_1+x_2 \le 1$

I guess you know how to graph these inequalities to show the feasible region?

Comment: thanks Tomi, I'll give it a try